# How to make an NFT out of an image using Solidity?

Tags: dapps, erc-721, nft

Over the last few days (while following a tutorial) I made a web app where I could make a NFT out of a color(e.g. #FFFFFF), so my question is if a client could upload a picture to my web app how would I mint that picture.

What exactly am I minting and where would I store that picture.

(I am a beginner so go easy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t mint “the picture”. You mint *a token*, i.e. you `Transfer` ownership of a new `tokenId` (e.g. 123) in your contract `from` nobody `to` your user. That’s all there is to minting an NFT.

Now, if your (let us say, ERC-721) contract goes even further and implements the [`ERC721Metadata` extension](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721), it will be possible to query your contract for information about a particular `tokenID` on your contract, via `tokenURI(tokenID)`. So calling on your contract e.g. `tokenURI(123)` would return a URI identifying a JSON file somewhere that provides more info about token 123 on your contract. The ERC-721 standard specifies that the JSON file should include an `image` field, which is:

> A URI pointing to a resource with mime type image/* representing the asset to which this NFT represents.

This is where the picture comes into the… picture.

So to mint a user's picture, you need to:

1. Upload the picture somewhere (to a website or to IPFS)
2. Upload somewhere (to a website or to IPFS) a JSON file with `image` identifying the picture in Step 1
3. Update your contract so that when queried for `tokenURI(123)`, it will return a URI identifying the JSON file in Step 2

For Step 1 and 2 you could integrate your web app with a service like [nft.storage](https://nft.storage/).

P.S. Using `data:` URIs you could also store or generate the JSON and/or the image in the contract itself, but that might be more complicated to achieve, so let’s limit the scope of this answer to the more usual method described above.

Comment: I am more interested in the P.S. part (data:)